# Simple proof that n divides $\sum_{1\le k<n, \gcd(k,n)=1} k$

Tags: summation, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, cyclotomic-polynomials

I was reading about [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) defined as:

$$ \Phi_n(x) =
\prod_\stackrel{1\le k\le n}{\gcd(k,n)=1}
\left(x-e^{2i\pi\frac{k}{n}}\right)$$

The fact that the coefficients of these polynomials are integers has a consequence (just looking at constant coefficient of the polynomial) which is simple to state:

$$n | \left( \sum_{1\le k<n, \gcd(k,n)=1} k \right)$$

However, is there a more elementary proof of this second statement ?

Comment: As you see, you have stated it wrongly. It is the other way around: $n$ divides this sum.

Comment: Indeed, I will fix this, thank you for your help!